# Why is this RewriteRule broken?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok folks, I'm at a loss.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ poker/$1 [L]
```

Throws me a 500 error. If I remove the redirect and go to /poker/ manually it works. If I use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^$ poker/ [L]
```

The front page is shown (but the css not, because obviously anything after the / is not redirected.

What could cause this `(.*)` to break?

Before this rule is just this to remove www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z-]+)\.([a-z]{2,3})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After it is nothing that could interfere.

Comment: Have you tried using the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` directives to debug this?

Comment: There probably also is an error message in the apache error log.

Comment: Something I had problems with is a RewriteBase that broke RewriteRules. What do you have set for RewriteBase?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. RewriteBase is `/`. `RewriteLog "rewrite.log"` and `RewriteLog "/home/examplen/rewritelog.log"` both give me 500 errors on the entire server, not just this domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so easy.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ poker/$1 [L]
```

Gives an infinite loop. I just had to add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/poker
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ poker/$1 [L]
```

(or as I just found out, creating an empty .htaccess with just `RewriteEngine On` in the /poker/ dir did the trick as well).